# CVE-2018-11759 Vulnerable: Tomcat Connector mod_jk 1.2.4

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux, tomcat, connector

because Tomcat Connector mod_jk 1.2.4 is Vulnerable (CVE-2018-11759) i am forced to upgrade the Connector. The Vendor has advised to upgrade to version 1.2.46 or later (http://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi).

I use an Apache 2.4.20 Webserver (HTTP) on a Linux - Redhat OS.

So when i download and unzip Tomcat Connectors (mod_jk) 1.2.46 i can´t find any module for the Connector (mod_jk.so) to replace with the old one in the appache modules directory. Am I doing something wrong?

Best Regards

Comment: Dir you read [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html)?

Comment: Yes i do. In this Thread i need also the mod_jk.so....

Comment: Did you read the section "Building mod_jk on Unix"? You can also look at [this](http://www.diegoacuna.me/installing-mod_jk-on-apache-httpd-in-centos-6-x7-x/)

Comment: Btw, If you initial mod_jk install was from your distro repository, you can try to upgrade the package from the same repo, they normally fix vulnerabilities.

Comment: @xenoid you are our rescue. Thank you so much